# Confidence interval for standard deviation of small sample test when the unknown population var are equal

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

I have a question about attaining the confidence interval of the standard deviation

Question:

Periodically, customers of a brokerage firm are asked to evaluate their financial consultants. Higher ratings on client satisfaction surveys indicate better perceived service, with 7 the maximum service rating. Independent samples of service rating for two financial consultants are summarized here. Consultant A has 10 years of experience, while consultant B has 1 year of experience
$$
 \begin{align}
 Consultant A |& Consultant B \\ 
 \hline
 n_1 = 16 |& n_2 = 10\\
 \bar{X}_1 = 6.82 |& \bar{X}_2 = 6.25 \\
 s_1 = 0.64 |& s_2 = 0.75 
 \end{align}
$$

My implementation

$$
\S_p \pm \frac{\bar{X} - \bar{Y}}{ \sqrt{(1/n+1/m)}t_{24,.05/2}}  
$$

Do I use the pool estimator as the standard deviation?

Comment: You have not clearly stated what you are asking. The title seems to say one thing and the (vague partial) question leaves open other possibilities. Please clarify. Is the idea to find a pooled variance your idea, or an instruction? Your equation for $\S_p$ (meaning $S_p$??) makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unclear what you are trying to do. (1) Test whether mean ratings for A and B are significantly different, which I would guess from the problem you state. Or (2) assume equal variances and get a CI for $\sigma^2 = \sigma_A^2 = \sigma_B^2.$

**(1)** I see no reason to assume equal variances. To test $H_0: \mu_A = \mu_B$
against $H_a: \mu_A \ne \mu_B$ (or maybe $\mu_A > \mu_B$), I would use a Welch, separate variances t test (output below from Minitab). The CI matching a two-sided test is also given in the printout below. The P-value 6.4% > 5% indicates
no significant difference. Accordingly, the 95% CI includes 0, again indicating
no significant difference.

```
Two-Sample T-Test and CI 

Sample   N   Mean  StDev  SE Mean
1       16  6.820  0.640     0.16
2       10  6.250  0.750     0.24

Difference = μ (1) - μ (2)
Estimate for difference:  0.570
95% CI for difference:  (-0.036, 1.176)
T-Test of difference = 0 (vs ≠): T-Value = 1.99  P-Value = 0.064  DF = 16
```

*Note:* You can easily tell that this is a Welch t test because a pooled t test
would have $DF = 16 + 10 - 2 = 24,$ whereas the printout has $DF = 16.$

**(2)** Assuming equal population variances (both equal to $\sigma^2$), compute the pooled variance $S_p^2$
and use $24S_p^2/\sigma^2 \sim Chisq(24)$ to get a 95% CI for $\sigma^2.$
I doubt this is good statistical practice, but if you were *told* to assume
equal variances, and then to base a CI for $\sigma^2$ on that assumption, then this would be a way
to comply.

Comment: Why does Welch use only DF = 16 in this problem? I can't remember...does Welch only use the largest DF in general..?

Comment: Welch uses messy formula to adjust DF depending on sample variances and sample sizes. Lower for relatively different samp var. Result is btw the min of $n_1 -1$ and $n_2-1$ (at lowest) and $n_1 + n_2 - 2$ (at highest).